# Pictures dsplay "Bitmap" and not filename when I mouse over pictures in PDF

Tags: windows-10, pdf, microsoft-visio

I'm running Windows 10. I want to save a Visio file (Visio online plan 2) that contains pictures to PDF.
[image]

It's working fine, but when I hover the mouse over pictures the alt text displayed is `Bitmap` and not the filename. Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: When a picture is added to a Visio page there is no record kept of where that image came from. It could have been added as a Paste operation. So there is no filename stored with the image within Visio.

Comment: this issue is just in Windows 10, i tried it in Windows 7 with Visio 13 and it's perfectly display filename and not bitmap. is that problem come from Visio, PDF or Windows version ? how can i change bitmap in this case?

Comment: Can you post (or link to) a version that displays the filename?

Comment: Sure, you can find attached Visio file, PDF and the way i changed the picture's filename in this link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1opRSGFniD9tBNid5jnFhXg7qnX2DbW5X

Comment: That's the shape name, not the file name!

Comment: The file you linked to doesn't show anything when I hover over the shape.

Comment: I'm talking about display data when you hover over shapes in PDF not in Visio

Comment: Yes, I know. The PDF you linked to in the zip file doesn't show any data when you hover over the shape.

Comment: are you using Acrobat Reader ? else u can't see them